# One DC is pulling FSMO from an AD server that doesn't exist, other DC sees FSMO AOK

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016, fsmo

I have 2 DC, one onpremDC, one hostedDC. There was some previous work where an RDS server was made a DC and FSMO moved to it, then the hostedDC was made the DC & FSMO moved to it, then AD removed from the RDS server. However, the onpremDC still sees the RDSserver as holding all the FSMO (even though it is no longer an AD server). Each DC was only pointing to itself for DNS, so I fixed that, however "netdom query fsmo" from onpremDC still shows the RDSserver (that doesn't exist as an AD server now) as the holder. HostedDC shows itself as fsmo holder (which it should be). Obviously AD/dns/replication issues abound(per dcdiag/replmon). Onprem will be going away soon anyways, so I was wondering should I put more time in trying to fix onpremDC (thought was it wouldn't take long to fix it, then it could be cleanly decommissioned)? I am not 100% sure AD is perfectly healthy with cloudDC (all clients are only pointing to cloudDC currently & "seem" to be working), otherwise, I would be tempted to just decom onpremDC and run through any metadata/cleanup needed to purge any reference to onpremDC & if there are any leftovers of RDS-DC. Eventually, I'll add a second hostedDC for the environment, but that is not currently scheduled. If I should fix onpremDC first, how do I tell it to pull the correct server as the fsmo role holder, assuming that is the big issue that needs to be fixed first? All server 2016. Forest/Domain level 2016.

Comment: Rather difficult to get the FSMO roles updated if inbound replication isn't working. What is onpremDC's replication partner?

Comment: @GregAskew after doing a metadata cleanup with onpremdc, repadmin shows nothing. HostedDC shows onpremDC though.

Comment: status after using ntdsutil to metadata cleanup RDSdc 
"netdom query fsmo" 
onpremDC:
netdom query fsmo
Schema master               *** Warning: role owner is a deleted DC: CN=NTDS Settings\0ADEL:guid1,CN=RDSdc
Domain naming master     onpremDC.addomain.tld   ***** Before this pointed to the RDSdc, it was not pointing to itself
PDC                  *** Warning: role owner is a deleted DC: 0ADEL:guid1,CN=RDSdc
RID pool manager            *** Warning: role owner is a deleted DC: 0ADEL:guid1,CN=RDSdc
Infrastructure master       *** Warning: role owner is a deleted DC: 0ADEL:guid1,CN=RDSdc